# Magento2.3 Admin error of tinymce

Tags: magento2.3, tinymce

I have installed

> https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4

Still, getting admin error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)



Failed to load plugin: noneditable from url https://shopycatch.com.au/new/pub/static/version1592137818/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/plugins/noneditable/plugin.js
```

tiny_mce_4 is the folder in between